# User Interface in JDBC - Viewing of table

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I want my program to output the `TRANSACTION` table using the `JTable` and the window appears but there's no table existing.

This part has been resolved
*SQL exception occuredjava.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

    SQL exception occuredjava.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation*

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.sql.* ; 
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ShowTransaction extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    final JButton mainMenuButton = new JButton("Main Menu");

    static ShowTransaction show = new ShowTransaction();

    public ShowTransaction(){
        super("Show Transactions");
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainMenuButton.setName("main");


        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@VAIO:49160:xe","mariel","1234");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM transaction");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[][] data = {
                    {rs.getInt("trans_num"), rs.getInt("trans_custnum"), rs.getInt("trans_payment"), rs.getString("trans_paymentdesc"), rs.getString("trans_cust_credcard"), rs.getInt("trans_change")}
                };
                String[] headers = {"Transaction Number", "Customer Number", "Payment", "Method of Payment", "Credit Card", "Change"};

                JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
                contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                contentPane.add(mainMenuButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                pack();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
        }

        mainMenuButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(mainMenuButton.getName().equals(((Component)e.getSource()).getName())){
            AdminMode admin = new AdminMode();
            admin.setVisible(true);
            admin.setResizable(false);
            admin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            admin.setSize(400,300);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        new ShowTransaction().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT: The `TRANSACTION` table in my sql developer is like [image: this].

Comment: What does the `transaction` table look like?

Comment: Using SQL keywords as table or column names is a very bad idea.  You should decompose this problem so the UI and database classes are separate.  Get the database access working perfectly, then marry it with the UI.  You don't close any of your SQL classes, which is a very bad idea too.  Lots wrong with this code.

Comment: Wild guess: Change `rs.getInt("trans_paymentdesc")` to `rs.getString("trans_paymentdesc")`;

Comment: I'll edit it out so you could see the table. I changed to getString and it does not error anymore but it does not view the table still.

Comment: You are re-creating the `JTable` for each row in the DB table, which is probably not what you want. Also, please share the full stack trace and the DB table description.

Comment: @duffymo ill try doing that

Comment: @MickMnemonic That's the full stack trace.I edited my post and added the table.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend renaming that table to CustomerTransaction; anything other than the [Oracle keyword transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/sql_keywords-t.htm).

Start with a simple Java interface:

```
package dao;

public interface CustomerTransactionDao {
    List<CustomerTransaction> find();
}
```

Then there's an implementation class:

```
package dao;

public class CustomerTransactionDaoImpl implements CustomerTransactionDao {

    // Think about column and table names.  They should be descriptive.  No need for "trans_; you know they're in the customer transaction table already.
    private static final String BASE_SELECT_SQL = "select id, customerId, paymentAmount, paymentDescription, creditCardNumber, change from customerTransaction "; 

    public List<CustomerTransaction> find() {
        List<CustomerTransaction> customerTransactions = new ArrayList<CustomerTransaction>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            // Query and mapping logic here.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Database access error", e);
        } finally {
            // close your resources in individual try/catch blocks inside the method.
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        } 
        return customerTransactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<CustomerTransaction> find();` errors but i added the import `java.util.List;` but it still errors at `CustomerTransaction` in `List<CustomerTransaction> find();`

Comment: It's not close to complete.  It's a skeleton to be fleshed out.  I didn't compile or run it.  It's an example to lead a new programmer down a path.  Not intended to be production code.  You should read it, understand it, and add in the bits that I deliberately left out so you could learn something.

Comment: Nice. You could also use try-with-resources to simplify the statement and result set handling.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm still stuck in my pre-JDK8 style.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new 2D Array in the loop. You will only ever have data for the last row from the ResultSet that you read.

Instead you logic should be something like:

```
String[] headers = {"Transaction Number", "Customer Number", .. };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0);

while (rs.next())
{
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    data.addElement( row );
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
connection.close();

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

The above code starts with an empty TableModel with just the column headings. Then it adds data for each row in the ResultSet.

If you want to create a custom Object for your CustomerTransaction then you also need to create a custom TableModel. Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an approach that shows how this can be done.